# save IPv4 address for different WIFI

Tags: wifi, tcp

I have a macbook pro, that I use at work and in my house,

the problem is that i have to set up manually the TCP/IP IPv4 address for each place,
the address doesn't change once im on a location,
but I have to change it manually when I go to the office and when I get home,

So how can I save it so that when I connect a specific WIFI the IPv4 address will get configured specially for that place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I create a location for places like that.  I have the default location(Auto) for my house but for each of my job sites I have a location with specific hard-coded IP/DNS.  You can create a location in Systems Perf -> Network.  Then to select each location go to the Apple icon -> location -> xxx.  That is the simplest way I think to do it.